# On se verra/On se voit quand tu seras libre/quand tu es libre ?

Tags: grammaire, temps-grammatical, concordance-des-temps, futur

Which one of these combinations are correct :

> (1) On se voit quand t'es libre.
>  
>   (2) On se voit quand tu seras libre.
>   (3) On se verra quand t'es libre.
>   (4) On se verra quand tu seras libre.

Sometimes I heard people use one and sometimes another. In English I think we only say either of the two options :

> We see again when you are free. -> This is less frequently heard
>   We'll see again when you are free.

without future tense in the second phrase after "*when*".

Just for confirmation : Is it true we never say the following ? And why ?

> On se verra quand tu vas être libre.

Comment: I notice that neither of your two English translations include “each other” (which is how I would translate, perhaps incorrectly, “se voir”: “We see [**each other**] again when you are free. /We'll see [**each other**] again when you are free.“ Is this simply an unintended omission, or are you translating “se voit/se verra” as “we see/we’ll see [**about that**] again?  (which might be totally correct if my translation is wrong)

Comment: Hi, you are correct. The full translation is indeed "We'll see each other again". But there are some nuances here in context : "see" here carries the meaning of "meet", which translates to "We'll meet again", and "we'll meet again" implies "meet each other". If we say "We'll see John again" or "We'll see" then it's another story. "We'll see" (without "again") means "Let's wait and see what 's going to happen" as in "Do you think they will get a divorce" - "We'll see". "We'll see again" does not carry this meaning. I am not a linguist so I tried my best to explain.

Comment: Another note : "We'll see about that again" does not sounds right to me. "We'll see about that" carries the meaning of something unknown, uncertain in the future "let's wait and see", so it does not go well with "again". "We'll see John again" signifies that has happened before.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### Time consistency

`2` and `3` are incorrect because the time used for each verb is inconsistent.

The most correct sentence is future: "*On se verra quand tu seras libre.*"

Sometimes though, present can be used to express a future that is not that far: "*On se voit quand tu es libre.*"

#### Future with *aller*

A near future can also be expressed using *aller* with an infinitive form: "*On va se voir.*"

Yet, the suggestion is indeed incorrect: "*On se verra quand tu vas être libre.*" There is a time inconsistency but I fail to express the rule about it.

This syntax is mainly spoken and spoken language tend to bend or escape the rules. Sentences using this construction are often short and I can't think of an example with another verb in the same sentence.

Comment: The Op’s examples of “se voir” in the future (se verra) all use just “voir” & not “REvoir,” even though the familiar “tu”/”t’es” give the feeling that these two people know each other & will not be seeing each other for the very first time.  Is “REvoir” unnecessary because the notion of “again” is somehow contained in “voir” (in these examples, at least)? If the time frame for their next meeting were further in the future would “REvoir” be required/more appropriate? eg, “On se voit/se verra DEMAIN [quand tu es/seras libre] as opposed to  “On se REverra l’ANNéE PROCHAINE [quand tu seras libre].

Comment: @PapaPoule You are quite correct: this construction ("_on_", "_tu_") implies the involved people know each other. I guess the English translation is used in the same way: "We'll see each other soon/when you'll have some time." "_Se revoir_" is less used and, as you indicate, feels less out of place when you are speaking of meeting again in a not-so-near future, having to spend some time gap without seeing each other "_On se reverra au prochain nouvel an._" But then again, between people who know each other quite well, you can be quite informal: "_On se verra au prochain nouvel an._"

Comment: Not in  OP's suggestion but correct/accepted  "On se verra *dès* que tu es libre".

Comment: @Archemar Leaves me unsatisfied. It is not time consistent and, in regard of my explanation, it is more confusing than helpful, I think.